# How can I change account type google pay from organization to personal

Tags: google-play-console, google-pay

I created google play console account with personal.But when I verify id , I need to fill organization information but my account type is personal. And then , when I check my payment in google pay for my play console account, account type is organization . How can I do that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question and not a programming question. Contact Google Pay support directly for questions related to your specific account. We do not provide customer service support for off-site vendors or services. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). For more information about this site, see the [help].

Comment: Have you solve it? I'm in the same situation